# join array of objects by using one property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an array of objects with a few properties, such as 'value' and 'label'.

`array.join(' ')` of course gives me "[object] [object]", but instead I need to get a string of the 'value' properties of all objects, separated by a space.

What is the shortest way to do this, and is this possible without writing a for loop?

Comment: Are your objects alike? In other words, could they be made from a single constructor function? If so, then you could just add a `.toString()` method to your `Constructor.prototype` object to define how it should look when converted to a string. Then you can just do `array.join(" ")`

Comment: ...[here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2fYvN/). This would be nicer than having to manually map the array to new values to join.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) - [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) not used because of IE < 9 support

For [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) - use [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for old browser support

```
$.map(array, function(obj){return JSON.stringify(obj)}).join(' ')
```

Update: To get the value properties

```
var string = $.map(array, function(obj){
    return obj.value
}).join(' ');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ut7RN/)

Comment: It seems you are missing `return` statement.

Comment: It seems I have badly explained. I edited my question, as what I need is a space separated string of all 'value' properties of the objects in the array.

Comment: @StevenDeGroote can you give an example for `[{name: 'name1', age: 30, value: 'v1'},{name: 'name2', age: 27, value: 'v2'}]`

Comment: I worked it out. I simply needed `$.map(array, function(obj){return obj.value}).join(' ')`. Thanks for showing the way!

Comment: Note for those who are using an ES5 shim or don't care about IE8 or below and want to avoid jquery, the syntax is almost the same.  Instead of `$.map(array, function(...` use `array.map(function(...`

Answer (score 8):

Use `Array.map`:

```
let data = [
  {
    "animal": "cat",
    "name": "Fluffy"
  },
  {
    "animal": "dog",
    "name": "Bowser"
  },
  {
    "animal": "cat",
    "name": "Felix"
  }
]
```

Now extract the names using `.map`:

```
let names = data.map(item => item.name)


let nameString = names.join(' ')
```

And now `nameString` contains `Fluffy Bowser Felix`.