# JavaScript: join properties of an array

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
let checks = document.querySelectorAll("#tableEvents input[type='checkbox']");
checks.forEach(e => {
    console.log(e.checked);
});
```

`checks` is then an array of `inputs`, and the console shows the expected output, i.e.:

```
true
false
false
true
```

My goal is to join these values: `true,false,false,true`.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39060365/881712) solution:

```
let values = checks.map(item => item.checked);
let joined = values.join();
```

but it returned:

> Uncaught TypeError: checks.map is not a function

Of course, I can just build up the string by myself:

```
let s = "";
checks.forEach(e => { s += e.checked + ","; })
s.slice(0, -1)
```

but I'm trying to learn a more elegant way, if it exists.

Comment: Make an array of the NodeList `querySelectorAll` returns.

Comment: The result of `querySelectorAll` isn't an array, even if it looks alike. It is instead a `NodeList`, but you can convert it to array using `Array.from(...)`

Comment: `[...checks].join(' ')` should probably work as well.